# Tic Tac Toe game in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, tic-tac-toe

I'd like to get an opinion on the code I've made for a Tic Tac Toe game in C++. I'm pretty new to C++ but I'd like to improve. I haven't been able to think of any improvements.

One bug I'd like to figure out later is that if a user enters values that aren't two separate integers the program seems to loop as if `stdin` is reading in those values repeatedly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int winner_yet(char board[4][4]) {
    if (
        (board[1][1] == 'x' && board[1][2] == 'x' && board[1][3] == 'x' ) ||
        (board[2][1] == 'x' && board[2][2] == 'x' && board[2][3] == 'x' ) ||
        (board[3][1] == 'x' && board[3][2] == 'x' && board[3][3] == 'x' ) ||
        (board[1][1] == 'x' && board[2][1] == 'x' && board[3][1] == 'x' ) ||
        (board[1][2] == 'x' && board[2][2] == 'x' && board[3][2] == 'x' ) ||
        (board[1][3] == 'x' && board[2][3] == 'x' && board[3][3] == 'x' ) ||
        (board[1][1] == 'x' && board[2][2] == 'x' && board[3][3] == 'x' ) ||
        (board[1][3] == 'x' && board[2][2] == 'x' && board[3][1] == 'x' )
        ) {
        return 1;
    } else if (
        (board[1][1] == 'o' && board[1][2] == 'o' && board[1][3] == 'o' ) ||
        (board[2][1] == 'o' && board[2][2] == 'o' && board[2][3] == 'o' ) ||
        (board[3][1] == 'o' && board[3][2] == 'o' && board[3][3] == 'o' ) ||
        (board[1][1] == 'o' && board[2][1] == 'o' && board[3][1] == 'o' ) ||
        (board[1][2] == 'o' && board[2][2] == 'o' && board[3][2] == 'o' ) ||
        (board[1][3] == 'o' && board[2][3] == 'o' && board[3][3] == 'o' ) ||
        (board[1][1] == 'o' && board[2][2] == 'o' && board[3][3] == 'o' ) ||
        (board[1][3] == 'o' && board[2][2] == 'o' && board[3][1] == 'o' )
        ) {
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}


bool game_finished(int valid_points[3][3]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (valid_points[i][j] == 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "GAME OVER / CAT SCRATCH OR WHATEVER IT'S CALLED\n";

    return true;
}

int draw_board (int x, int y, char board_array[4][4]) {
    std::cout << std::string(50, '\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        std::cout << "\t\t";
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            std::cout << " " << board_array[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::string(4, '\n');
    return 0;
}

bool plot_point (int x, int y, int valid_points[3][3],char marker, char board_array[4][4]) {
    int board_num_x = x-1;
    int board_num_y = y-1;
    if (valid_points[board_num_x][board_num_y] == 1) {
        valid_points[board_num_x][board_num_y] = 0;
        board_array[y][x] = marker;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

int toggle_turn(char &marker) {
    if (marker == 'x') {
        marker = 'o';
    } else {
        marker = 'x';
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    bool game_status = true;
    while (game_status) {
        int x,y;
        std::string input, general_input;
        char marker = 'x';
        char board[4][4] = {
            {' ','1','2','3'},
            {'1','-','-','-'},
            {'2','-','-','-'},
            {'3','-','-','-'}
        };
        int valid_points[3][3] = {
            {1,1,1},
            {1,1,1},
            {1,1,1}
        };

        draw_board(4,4,board);

        while (game_finished(valid_points) == false && winner_yet(board) == 0) {
            std::cout << "Choose your point e.g. x y\n";

            std::cin >> x;
            std::cin >> y;

            if  (std::cin.fail()) {
                std::cout << "Invalid input, please start over\n";
                x = 0, y = 0;
                exit(0);
            } else {
                if (plot_point(x,y,valid_points,marker,board)) {
                    draw_board(4,4,board);
                    toggle_turn(marker);
                } else {
                    draw_board(4,4,board);
                    std::cout << "Invalid move, please try again\n";
                }

            }

        }
        std::cout << "Player " << winner_yet(board) << " wins the round!\n";
        std::cout << "Would you like to play again?\n";
        std::cin >> general_input;
        if (general_input == "no" || general_input == "No") {
            game_status = false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. Unfortunately, your question in the current is unclear about what you are asking. Are you asking "How can this code be improved excluding the bug?" or "How can bugs be fixed in the following code?" Note that if you are asking "How can bugs be fixed in the following code?" it does not belong on CR, and should be moved to [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @MannyMeng I'm trying to find out how I can improve the code overall. I was merely mentioning that bug in particular. I want to just learn better application design and C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Miscellaneous suggestions (in no particular order):

---

The `winner_yet()` function has two copy-pasted hunks of code. You can trim one of the blocks by just passing the *symbol* you want to test against as a function parameter. I would also give it a name like `symbol_wins` or `player_wins`.

```
bool symbol_wins(char board[4][4], char symbol) {
    if ((board[1][1] == symbol && board[1][2] == symbol && board[1][3] == symbol) ||
        (board[2][1] == symbol && board[2][2] == symbol && board[2][3] == symbol) ||
        (board[3][1] == symbol && board[3][2] == symbol && board[3][3] == symbol) ||
        (board[1][1] == symbol && board[2][1] == symbol && board[3][1] == symbol) ||
        (board[1][2] == symbol && board[2][2] == symbol && board[3][2] == symbol) ||
        (board[1][3] == symbol && board[2][3] == symbol && board[3][3] == symbol) ||
        (board[1][1] == symbol && board[2][2] == symbol && board[3][3] == symbol) ||
        (board[1][3] == symbol && board[2][2] == symbol && board[3][1] == symbol)) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Done! Now just call it with either `'x'` or `'o'`. Also notice that since the return of such method is a `true` or `false` query, we use the `bool` (boolean) type instead.

If you want you could even trim this big conditional further by making some cleaver use of loops and integer math. If you look closely, you'll be see that the in the width or X dimension of the matrix there is a pattern of indexes for the three tests. That could be turned into a loop. The height or Y direction also displays a pattern in the indexing. I'll leave the rest as an exercise to you if you wanna try to figure out a shorter way to implement the test.

---

In `toggle_turn()`, instead or returning a meaningless zero, why not return the new symbol instead?

```
char toggle_turn(char current_symbol) {
    return (current_symbol == 'x') ? 'o' : 'x';
}
```

Notice here that you can use the [*ternary operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C.2B.2B) to make this code more concise.

---

Since you don't use `argc` and `argv` in `main`, just redeclare the function to:

```
int main() {
```

Also, you have a lost `exit(0)` call in the middle of `main`. `exit()` is a low-level function of the C library and it is not meant to be used on a regular C++ program. In your case, you should instead have simply returned from `main`.

---

Overall, it looks quite good. You haven't used global variables (+1 to that) or any other questionable things like `using namespace` or `goto`. Good work!

Next step, I think, would be turning this set of free functions into a class. Object Oriented Programming (OOP) is a very popular paradigm in C++ programs, so you should give it a try any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion 1: Create a separate function to get user input**

I would put the code to get user input for `x` and `y` in a separate function. Also, add the option to let the user quit the game if they want to:

```
bool getInput(int& x, int& y)
{
   while ( true )
   {
      std::cout << "Choose your point e.g. x y. Enter q to quit.\n";
      std::string input;
      std::getline(std::cin, input);
      if (std::cin)
      {
         if ( input[0] == 'q' )
         {
            return false;
         }

         std::istringstream str(input);
         if ( str >> x >> y )
         {
            // Sucessfully read the input.
            return true;
         }

         // If there was a problem in getting x and y from the input
         // continue with the loop.
      }
      else
      {
         // Did not get the line of input
         return false;
      }
   }

   // Never should come here.
   // Add a return statement to keep the compiler happy.
   return false;
}
```

With that, you can change this block of code in `main`

```
  while (game_finished(valid_points) == false && winner_yet(board) == 0) {
     std::cout << "Choose your point e.g. x y\n";

     std::cin >> x;
     std::cin >> y;

     if  (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Invalid input, please start over\n";
        x = 0, y = 0;
        exit(0);
     } else {
        if (plot_point(x,y,valid_points,marker,board)) {
           draw_board(4,4,board);
           toggle_turn(marker);
        } else {
           draw_board(4,4,board);
           std::cout << "Invalid move, please try again\n";
        }
     }
  }
```

to

```
  while (game_finished(valid_points) == false && winner_yet(board) == 0) {
     if (!getInput(x, y) ) {
        return 0;
     }

     if (plot_point(x,y,valid_points,marker,board)) {
        draw_board(4,4,board);
        toggle_turn(marker);
     } else {
        draw_board(4,4,board);
        std::cout << "Invalid move, please try again\n";
     }
  }
```

**Suggestion 2: Remove redundant data**

You are using `valid_points` to keep track of whether a slot is open for placing a marker. You can just as easily use `board` to keep track of that information. If `board[x][y]` is `'_'`, it is open for placing a marker. Otherwise, it is not.

**Suggestion 3: Make `board` a `3 x 3` array**

You are using an `4 x 4` array for board simply for the convenience of printing the `board`. The true state of the board is a `3 x 3` array. Hence, I would suggesting using:

```
  char board[3][3] = {
     {'-','-','-'},
     {'-','-','-'},
     {'-','-','-'}
  };
```

That would, of course, change all the functions that depend on `board` to be a `4 x 4` array.

Comment: Ahh I see, I appreciate the help. These are just things I didn't think of.